# Starting an animation in python, letting it run for X frames then pausing it, and then having the second half of a script run

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have a script that adds rigid bodies to a scene, then I'd like them to fall into a box and then export their final resting place, but need to delete objects that do not end up in the box(as to only export the box and the objects within it and not the ones that miss the box). Is there a way to run part of the script, animate 40 frames then pause the animation, and then run the rest of the script?
Something like (the box is already in place and in practice it will be multiple objects being added in semi random positions)

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 3), scale=(1, 1, 1))

bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()

bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

run for 40 frames

animation stop

rest of the script

Thank you!

Comment: I think this might be a good use case for "apply visual transform"